# Configuration NFS v3 Kerberos on Centos 5.x

Tags: nfs, kerberos

Platform:
CentOS release 5.5

Installed the kb5-libs , krb5-server  krb5-workstation in the NFS Server. 
The NFS Server IP and Machine IP are different.

Machine IP : 172.xx.xx.xx
NFS Server IP: 169.254.xx.xx

Installed the rpcidmapd and rpcgssd , nfsd, portmap , ntpd

Setup the /etc/krb5.conf

[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = KRBNFS.NET
 default_keytab_name = FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 forwardable = yes
 allow_weak_crypto = true

[realms]
 KRBNFS.NET = {
  kdc = nfsserver.krbnfs.net:88
  admin_server = nfsserver.krbnfs.net:749
  default_domain = krbnfs.net
 }

[domain_realm]
 .krbnfs.net  = KRBNFS.NET
 krbnfs.net = KRBNFS.NET

[appdefaults]
 pam = {
   debug = false
   ticket_lifetime = 36000
   renew_lifetime = 36000
   forwardable = true
   krb4_convert = false
 }

[kdc]
 profile = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kdc.conf

Here:
/etc/hosts
169.254.xx.xx nfsserver.krbnfs.net krbnfs.net
169.254.xx.xx nfsclient.krbnfs.net

Note: If I use the same IP without Kerberos then mount works fine.

/var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kdc.conf
[kdcdefaults]
 v4_mode = nopreauth
 kdc_tcp_ports = 88

[realms]
 KRBNFS.NET = {
  #master_key_type = des3-hmac-sha1
  acl_file = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl
  dict_file = /usr/share/dict/words
  admin_keytab = /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.keytab
  supported_enctypes = aes256-cts:normal aes128-cts:normal des3-hmac-sha1:normal arcfour-hmac:normal des-hmac-sha1:normal des-cbc-md5:normal des-cbc-crc:normal des-cbc-crc:v4 des-cbc-c
 }

/var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl
root/admin@KRBNFS.NET   *

hostname
Machine Name : Centos-5

cat /etc/resolv.conf 
search localdomain
nameserver 127.0.0.1

Kernel modules installed
rpcsec_gss_krb5        41480  0 
auth_rpcgss            75296  2 rpcsec_gss_krb5,nfsd
sunrpc                176968  15 rpcsec_gss_krb5,nfsd,nfs_acl,auth_rpcgss,lockd

Added Principal
root/admin@KRBNFS.NET
nfs/nfsserver.krbnfs.net
nfs/nfsclient.krbnfs.net

kinit to root/admin

ktadd to root/admin@KRBNFS.NET , nfs/nfsserver.krbnfs.net , nfs/nfsclient.krbnfs.net

/usr/kerberos/bin/klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: root/admin@KRBNFS.NET

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
01/20/07 23:43:58  01/21/07 23:43:58  krbtgt/KRBNFS.NET@KRBNFS.NET

Kerberos 4 ticket cache: /tmp/tkt0
klist: You have no tickets cached

In the NFS Client side,
Installed the rpc.gssd and kernel modules.
Setup the Keytab file similar to that in server.

hostname
localhost

In the /etc/exports
/test                   nfsclient.krbnfs.net(rw,insecure,no_root_squash,async,sec=krb5)

On trying mount getting error as 
[root@localhost(5) ~]# mount -vvvv -t nfs -o sec=krb5,rw nfsserver.krbnfs.net:/test /mpc_tst
mount: trying 169.254.2.254 prog 100003 vers 3 prot tcp port 2049
mount: trying 169.254.2.254 prog 100005 vers 3 prot udp port 32767
mount.nfs: Permission denied
[root@localhost(5) ~]#

If you need more info to help me kindly post. I can share more details.
Also, need help if the NFS v3 Kerberos configuration is OK ?

Comment: CentOS 5 is EOL. Upgrade to something newer.

Comment: The product is operational and hence we cannot upgrade the operating system. But by looking at the configuration can you suggest some solution. Kindly note, I do not have a DNS setup